# How to design this inline-banner with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a promo banner for my website, and I found this model right here:

[image: Banner]

I'm using bootstrap and I'm thinking to create it using Flex but I don't know how... How to arrange and style the first square? It's like giving it a width of 10% and the rest of container 90%?

Here's what I think of:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="/img/bubble.png" class="left-img">
        </div>

        <div class="middle">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum</p>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Action Button</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Is this HTML correct?

How the CSS would look like for container classes?

Please, help a brother :(

Comment: easy to design with flexbox -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ - `flex-grow` is properly the part that you're missing by using flex

Comment: Thank you, flex-grow might help me indeed. Is my HTML correct for this banner or can be done easily? Thank you!

Comment: no need to wrap the 3 elements in a div they would work without a div and only the wrapping container as parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```css
.dummy-img{
    width: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container mt-3">
  
  <p>Use .flex-grow-1 on a flex item to take up the rest of the space:</p>
  <p class="bg-light">kindly put your own image and remove styling on image. Also you can use .flex-wrap class on div where d-flex is added to wrap items on different screens</p>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center bg-light mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">
    <img class="dummy-img" src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/153-1537658_twitter-comment-icon-png-clipart-png-download-topic.png"> 
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1">
       <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 ">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill">Action Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `flex` property you can put your divs sizes in relation. 
I set your left one to `1` and the other two siblings to `4.5` which basically means they are in the ratio of 10% to 45% to 45%.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 157, 210);
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.middle {
  flex: 4.5;
}

.right {
  flex: 4.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="/img/bubble.png" class="left-img">
  </div>

  <div class="middle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Action Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could additionally make us of the `aspect-ratio` property if you want the left part to be an exact square.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 157, 210);
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.middle {
  flex: 4.5;
}

.right {
  flex: 4.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="/img/bubble.png" class="left-img">
  </div>

  <div class="middle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Action Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```